# No muestra los datos de la Tabla de React en mi .xlsx generado

Tags: reactjs, excel, frontend

Tengo mi funcion la cual se encarga de cargar los datos de mi tabla uno es para las columnas y las otras para las filas, pero al momento de descargar el .xlsx solo muestra los datos de las columnas pero no de las filas, coloque unos logs para ver si en realidad estan los datos y efectivamente si muestra los datos de mi tabla pero de alguna manera no los carga en el .xlsx

este es mi funcion para desacargar el .xlsx

```
handleDownloadExcel = () => {
    const { usuariosColumns, usuariosData } = this.state;

    const sheetData = usuariosData.map(item =>
        usuariosColumns.map(column => {
            console.log('Item:', item);
            console.log('Column:', column);
            return item[column];
        })
    );

    const ws = utils.aoa_to_sheet([usuariosColumns, ...sheetData]);
    const wb = utils.book_new();
    utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Usuarios');

    const wbout = write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });

    const blob = new Blob([wbout], {
        type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    });

    saveAs(blob, 'usuarios.xlsx'); // Utiliza saveAs para descargar el archivo
}
```

y este es como lo invoco

```
<Tooltip title="Descargar Excel" placement="left">
                    <button
                        style={{ position: 'relative', marginLeft: '20px', cursor: 'pointer', border: 'none', background: 'none', padding: '0' }}
                        onClick={this.handleDownloadExcel}
                    >
                        <DownloadIcon />
                    </button>
                </Tooltip>
```